# Will I learn most from reading proofs, proof outlines, or solving problems?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice

I have been self studying some topics in theoretical statistics for a bit over a year but still do not have a good balance between reading proofs in detail, reading proofs to get a general idea and solving exercises. Solving exercises definitely feels the most productive, but I'd expect that reading proofs closely has a lot of value for growing my mathematical maturity. As a note, I'm mostly talking about proofs from literature, not textbook proofs.

- If a proof is hard enough that I need to spend hours going through it, am I just wasting my time? Do you have any tips for making this time more productive? (I usually try to follow each step and justify each claim.)
- Is there much value in skimming a proof? I still don't have enough experience that I can think "post-rigorously". Skimming proofs usually does not feel productive to me.

Comment: Problem solving and reading theory

Comment: This is very generalised advice (I am not an expert in statistics). Solving problems is always a good idea for understanding a mathematical topic. As for skimming proofs, that's a trick you need to learn and the way you learn it is to read proofs while looking for the proof patterns that keep reappearing . Writing down the significant lemmas (that may just appear as anonymous steps in a printed proof) is a useful and often instructive compromise between skimming and detailed verification of the every step in a proof. (Apologies if that just reads like apple pie.)

Comment: I really like that idea, I haven't yet tried to pull out lemmas that look familiar and could be useful elsewhere.

Comment: Solving problems that are just barely above your skill level - not too hard, not too easy.

Comment: Giving time to mathematical problems and learn by self study is never a waste of time. It always sharp our mind , make things more interesting and improve a researchtic mind in our brain which will later help you in PhD. But studying productively is much depends on knowledge of prerequisites associated with this course. And online courses at least help me much for the same.

Comment: I agree @rubikscube09 but then I'll spend all my time searching for the right problems :)

Comment: You shouldn't just read proofs, you should try to invent the proof before you read it; once you read part of the proof, you should try to finish it yourself; once you read the whole proof, you should try to reproduce it yourself with the book closed. And you should try to imagine how someone might have thought of the proof. What is the intuitive idea at the heart of the proof? Is there a perspective that makes the whole thing seem obvious? Can you see it at a glance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advice will be different for everyone. If you are looking to **learn the contents of a paper,**  I think what works for me is to concentrate on the parts where I am maximally confused.  If you read a theorem and think "hmm, seems reasonable, I can sorta see how to prove that" then *maybe* you can get away with just skimming over the proof if it's not too important.  On the other hand, if the theorem makes you say "WTF?" then maybe you need a much closer look.  Of course, if you're new to the field, most theorems are going to be in the second category.

On the other hand, if you're looking to **practice your skills** or **test your understanding** you should read a paper in a very different way.  Try taking the statements of the theorems and proving them yourself first before reading the proofs. The theorems in the first category above are especially good candidates for this.  And of course if it is a textbook with exercises, do those.

I've also found it useful to read papers multiple times at different levels of detail.  First time skimming, then reading, then verifying most details, then verifying 99% of the details.  It's also often useful to read a paper **out of order.** Skip to the important stuff first, the main theorems.  Then go back and see how the lemmas are useful towards that goal.

Comment: +1 Re: the last paragraph, I got the key idea for my first paper by reading another paper backwards.